# How to convert a JSON structure into a dataclass object tree?

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON data structure. Every object has a field called `"type"`.

```py
json_data_str = """
{
    "type" : "Game",
    "levels" : [
        {
            "type": "Level",
            "map" : {
                "type" : "SquareRoom",
                "name" : "Level 1",
                "width" : 100,
                "height" : 100
            },
            "waves" : [
                {
                    "type" : "Wave",
                    "enemies" : [
                        {
                            "type" : "Wizard",
                            "name" : "Gandalf"
                        },
                        {
                            "type" : "Archer",
                            "name" : "Legolass"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
"""
```

And I want to convert this into an object tree composed of the following classes

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List

@dataclass
class GameObject:
    ...

@dataclass
class Character(GameObject):
    name: str

@dataclass
class Wave(GameObject):
    enemies: List[Character]

@dataclass
class Wizard(Character):
    ...

@dataclass
class Archer(Character):
    ...

@dataclass
class Map(GameObject):
    name: str

@dataclass
class SquareRoom(Map):
    width: int
    height: int

@dataclass
class Level(GameObject):
    waves: List[Wave]
    map: Map
    
@dataclass
class Game(GameObject):
    levels: List[Level]
```

I can unpack a simple json object into a dataclass quite easily using the `**` operator: e.g

```py
json_data_str = """
{
   "type" : "Person"
   "name" : "Bob"
   "age" : 29
}
"""

class GameObject(ABC):
    ...

@dataclass
class Person(GameObject):
    name: str
    age: int

game_object_registry: Dict[str, Type[GameObject]] = {}
game_object_registry['Person'] = Person

json_obj = json.loads(json_data_str)
obj_type = json_obj['type']
del json_obj['type']
ObjType = game_object_registry[obj_type]
ObjType(**json_obj)
```

But how can I extend this to work with nested objects?

I want it to create this data class instance:

```py
game = Game(levels=[Level(map=SquareRoom(name="Level 1", width=100, height=100), waves=[Wave([Wizard(name="Gandalf"), Archer(name="Legolass")])])])
```

Here is my best attempt. It doesn't really make sense, but it might be a starting point. I realise this logic doesn't make sense, but I cannot come up with a function that does make sense.

```py
def json_to_game_object(json_obj: Any, game_object_registry: Dict[str, Type[GameObject]]) -> Any:

    if type(json_obj) is dict:
        obj_type: str = json_obj['type']
        del json_obj['type']
        ObjType = game_object_registry[obj_type]
        for key, value in json_obj.items():
            logging.debug(f'Parsing feild "{key}:{value}"')
            json_to_game_object(value, game_object_registry)
            if type(value) is dict:
                logging.debug(f'Creating object of type {ObjType} with args {value}')
                return ObjType(**value)
    elif type(json_obj) is list:
        logging.debug(f'Parsing JSON List')
        for elem in json_obj:
            logging.debug(f'Parsing list element "{json_obj.index(elem)}"')
            json_to_game_object(elem, game_object_registry)
    else:
        logging.debug(f'Parsing value')
```

Comment: I don't see the point of using dumb data class objects here.  Eventually, you are going to want intelligence in these classes, right?  So rather than come up with a complicated over-general import, just let each class do its own import.  It knows what it wants.  I'll do up an example.

Comment: This is just a piece of example code. The real thing I want to know how to do is turn json data into a dataclass python object tree, ideally with some data validation steps. "Eventually, you are going to want intelligence in these classes, right?" - Not always. I have been exerimenting with functional programming and using single / multiple dispatch, instead of using instance methods or abstract methods etc. in order for single / multiple dispatch to work, I need to convert my json data into a python object, so it encodes the type information inside itself.

Comment: Do you have control on the json structure?

Comment: @balderman yes, I do

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, you could also use the [dataclass-wizard](https://dataclass-wizard.readthedocs.io/) library for this.

This should support dataclasses in `Union` types as of a recent version,
and note that as of *v0.19.0*, you can pass `tag_key` in the Meta config for the main dataclass, to configure the tag field name in the JSON object that maps to the dataclass in each `Union` type - which in your case defaults to the `type` field.

I've also removed this `type` field entirely in cases where it was not really needed -- note that you'd only need such a tag field when you have a field that maps to one or more dataclass types, via a `Union` declaration. The one main benefit of using a custom tag for each class, is that if you later decide to rename the class for instance, any existing JSON data can still be de-serialized into the nested dataclass model as expected.

The below example should work for Python 3.7+ with the included `__future__` import. This allows you to use [PEP 585](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/) and [PEP 604](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0604/)- style annotations, for a more convenient shorthand syntax.

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from dataclasses import dataclass

from dataclass_wizard import JSONWizard


@dataclass
class GameObject:
    ...


@dataclass
class Game(GameObject, JSONWizard):

    class _(JSONWizard.Meta):
        # Set tag key in JSON object; defaults to '__tag__' if not specified.
        tag_key = 'type'

    levels: list[Level]


@dataclass
class Level(GameObject):
    waves: list[Wave]
    # TODO: define other map classes
    map: SquareRoom | Map


@dataclass
class Wave(GameObject):
    enemies: list[Wizard | Archer]


@dataclass
class Character(GameObject):
    name: str


@dataclass
class Wizard(Character, JSONWizard):

    class _(JSONWizard.Meta):
        tag = 'Wizard'

    ...


@dataclass
class Archer(Character, JSONWizard):

    class _(JSONWizard.Meta):
        tag = 'Archer'

    ...


@dataclass
class Map(GameObject):
    name: str


@dataclass
class SquareRoom(Map, JSONWizard):

    class _(JSONWizard.Meta):
        tag = 'SquareRoom'

    width: int
    height: int


def main():
    json_data_str = """
    {
        "levels": [
            {
                "map": {
                    "type": "SquareRoom",
                    "name": "Level 1",
                    "width": 100,
                    "height": 100
                },
                "waves": [
                    {
                        "enemies": [
                            {
                                "type": "Wizard",
                                "name": "Gandalf"
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "Archer",
                                "name": "Legolass"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
    """

    game = Game.from_json(json_data_str)
    print(repr(game))
    print('Prettified JSON result:\n', game)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
Game(levels=[Level(waves=[Wave(enemies=[Wizard(name='Gandalf'), Archer(name='Legolass')])], map=SquareRoom(name='Level 1', width=100, height=100))])
Prettified JSON result:
 {
  "levels": [
    {
      "waves": [
        {
          "enemies": [
            {
              "name": "Gandalf",
              "type": "Wizard"
            },
            {
              "name": "Legolass",
              "type": "Archer"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "map": {
        "name": "Level 1",
        "width": 100,
        "height": 100,
        "type": "SquareRoom"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

---

If you want to save yourself some time and not have to manually define a `tag` for each dataclass in a `Union` type, you can also automate this process by enabling the `auto_assign_tags` flag on the main dataclass; this will default to assign the class name as the `tag` for each nested class. This also allows you to remove the `JSONWizard` usage from the nested dataclasses, so that you only have it on the main dataclass, as shown below.

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from dataclasses import dataclass

from dataclass_wizard import JSONWizard


@dataclass
class GameObject:
    ...


@dataclass
class Game(GameObject, JSONWizard):

    class _(JSONWizard.Meta):
        # Set tag key in JSON object; defaults to '__tag__' if not specified.
        tag_key = 'type'
        auto_assign_tags = True

    levels: list[Level]


@dataclass
class Level(GameObject):
    waves: list[Wave]
    # TODO: define other map classes
    map: SquareRoom | Map


@dataclass
class Wave(GameObject):
    enemies: list[Wizard | Archer]


@dataclass
class Character(GameObject):
    name: str


@dataclass
class Wizard(Character):
    ...


@dataclass
class Archer(Character):
    ...


@dataclass
class Map(GameObject):
    name: str


@dataclass
class SquareRoom(Map):
    width: int
    height: int
```

The only caveat with this approach, is if you later decide to rename a dataclass such as the `Archer` class, any existing JSON data can't be de-serialized without manually specifying a `tag` for the class.

The output should be the same as in the first example, where we explicitly specified a `tag` for each dataclass in a `Union` declaration.

---

If you need data validation or if you want to retain the `type` field in the JSON object, I'd also suggest [pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/) as another solution. In addition, you can use pydantic [drop-in dataclasses](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/dataclasses/) and retain the `@dataclass` usage for the rest of the model classes, as shown below.

```py
from typing import List, Union

from pydantic import BaseModel
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass
from typing_extensions import Literal


@dataclass
class GameObject:
    ...


@dataclass
class Character(GameObject):
    name: str


@dataclass
class Wizard(Character):
    type: Literal['Wizard']


@dataclass
class Archer(Character):
    type: Literal['Archer']


@dataclass
class Wave(GameObject):
    enemies: List[Union[Wizard, Archer]]


@dataclass
class Map(GameObject):
    name: str


@dataclass
class SquareRoom(Map):
    type: Literal['SquareRoom']
    width: int
    height: int


@dataclass
class Level(GameObject):
    waves: List[Wave]
    # TODO: define other map classes
    map: Union[SquareRoom, Map]


class Game(BaseModel, GameObject):
    levels: List[Level]


def main():
    json_data_str = """
    {
        "levels": [
            {
                "map": {
                    "type": "SquareRoom",
                    "name": "Level 1",
                    "width": 100,
                    "height": 100
                },
                "waves": [
                    {
                        "enemies": [
                            {
                                "type": "Wizard",
                                "name": "Gandalf"
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "Archer",
                                "name": "Legolass"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
    """

    game = Game.parse_raw(json_data_str)
    print(repr(game))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The output in this case is slightly different - note that when you print the `repr` of the `Game` object, you also see the `type` fields printed out, since technically it is a dataclass field.

```
Game(levels=[Level(waves=[Wave(enemies=[Wizard(name='Gandalf', type='Wizard'), Archer(name='Legolass', type='Archer')])], map=SquareRoom(name='Level 1', type='SquareRoom', width=100, height=100))])
```

Comment: @Blue7 Just a note that I added some updates so that a `type` field can be supported as the tag field. I updated my answer to reflect these changes.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have control over the JSON / dict structure. You can use a framework like [dacite](https://github.com/konradhalas/dacite).

It will let you map the data into your dataclasses.

Example (taken from dacite github) below:

```
@dataclass
class A:
    x: str
    y: int


@dataclass
class B:
    a: A


data = {
    'a': {
        'x': 'test',
        'y': 1,
    }
}

result = from_dict(data_class=B, data=data)

assert result == B(a=A(x='test', y=1))
```

Comment: Amazing, this is very close to what I am trying to do! The only downfall with this is that if I have two dataclasses with identical structure, this will not know which one to use. E.g, my Wizard and Archer. That is why I had the type field in my json. I might be able to investigate the sourcecode of dacite and reverse engineer a solution though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how do this export in an object-oriented way.  In my personal opinion, converting this to pure dataclass objects brings you no benefit over just keeping everything in a dictionary.  Here, each object can have its own behavior.

(I've now modified this to start adding repr handlers, so you can print the whole tree at once.)

```
json_data_str = """
{
    "type" : "Game",
    "levels" : [
        {
            "type": "Level",
            "map" : {
                "type" : "SquareRoom",
                "name" : "Level 1",
                "width" : 100,
                "height" : 100
            },
            "waves" : [
                {
                    "type" : "Wave",
                    "enemies" : [
                        {
                            "type" : "Wizard",
                            "name" : "Gandalf"
                        },
                        {
                            "type" : "Archer",
                            "name" : "Legolass"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
"""

import json

class GameObject():
    pass

class Game(GameObject):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.levels = [Level(k) for k in obj['levels']]
    def __repr__(self):
        s = f"<Game contains {len(self.levels)} levels:>\n"
        s += '\n'.join(repr(l) for l in self.levels)
        return s

class Character(GameObject):
    def __init__(self,obj):
        self.name = obj['name']


class Wave(GameObject):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.enemies = [game_object_registry[e['type']](e) for e in obj['enemies']]
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Wave contains {len(self.enemies)} enemies'


class Wizard(Character):
    def __init__(self,obj):
        super().__init__(obj)

class Archer(Character):
    def __init__(self,obj):
        super().__init__(obj)

class Map(GameObject):
    pass

class SquareRoom(Map):
    def __init__(self,obj):
        self.name = obj['name']
        self.widdth = obj['width']
        self.height = obj['height']

class Level(GameObject):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.waves = [Wave(e) for e in obj['waves']]
        self.map = game_object_registry[obj['map']['type']](obj['map'])
    def __repr__(self):
        s = f'<Level contains {len(self.waves)} waves>\n'
        s += '\n'.join(repr(w) for w in self.waves)
        return s

game_object_registry = {
    'Game': Game,
    'Wave': Wave,
    'Level': Level,
    'SquareRoom': SquareRoom,
    'Archer': Archer,
    'Map': Map,
    'Wizard': Wizard
}

json_obj = json.loads(json_data_str)

g = Game(json_obj)
print(g)
print(g.levels[0].waves[0].enemies[0].name)
```

Comment: This is quite nice. But one of the motivations for keeping the GameObjects dumb is to make it super easy to define new types. This method requires some parsing of the json in each class, and I wanted to create one generic function that will work for any object in the game_object_registry, and it will give a fairly sensible error if the json does not have the correct fields (which the "**args" method does). 

In this example, you would have to put data validation in every single class as they all are directly looking at the json. For classes with lots of fields, this will be annoying.

Comment: I also wanted my GameObjects part of the application to be completely seperate from the json part, and have the option to construct these clases without using a json obj (well, a dict), if I wanted to. Also your example only works for this particular example. I would like a function that will work with any set of classes, as long as it has the correct json to go along with it.

Comment: Given all that, then I don't see any point in making these classes.  A dict has the same functionality.

Comment: they do, but they need to be classes to work with single or multiple dispatch.